# How do I add/remove a user role based on subscription?

Tags: commerce

I have a product "Membership" that is set up as a subscription. When a user purchases this "Membership" I would like to assign them a "Member" role. How do I do this?

I have looked at the docs but they are incomplete for Commerce 2.

I have looked at [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license), but I'm not sure if it's production ready for 8/9 or even if it's the right choice.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is way too broad for this site, but since I just did this in a site of mine recently, here are some hints.

[Create an EventSubscriber](https://www.devlubo.com/tutorial/writing-custom-event-subscriber-drupal-8-drupal-commerce):

```
  /**
   * Set fields and roles for user accounts that purchase subscriptions.
   */
  public function postPlaceTransition(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
    $order = $event->getEntity();
    $customer = $order->getCustomer();
    $customer->addRole('MYROLE');
  }
```

Comment: Great thanks! I'll look into EventSubscriber. On a side note, how am I supposed to know if a question is way too broad? Just want to make sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: In general, instead of saying something like "the docs are incomplete," link to the doc page you read and the specific question that you have. If your question can have a specific, factual answer that is NOT a matter of opinion, it's appropriate for this site. If your question is likely to invite a discussion of numerous approaches, it's probably too broad for this site.  In that case, you should ask the question in the Drupal Slack channel, etc.